# Function not found error with xlcFreeMemory()

Tags: r

I'm trying to read Excel files in R and seem to be running into memory issues. As mentioned on this site and others I tried to use the `xlcFreeMemory()` function, but I get the error message: `this function could not be found`. What am I missing? And what are my other options to free memory?

Comment: Did you load `library(XLConnect)`?

Comment: (I'm new to R).  I had loaded library(xlsx) - I thought XLConnect was part of that library. I did try now loading library(XLConnect) and now that error does go away.  However, I continue to get the memory related error Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. I'll try the Java memory setting and see if that works.

Comment: The function not found error comes when a package hasn't been loaded. You should update your question (and its title) with the memory error.